# Shooting Method

Tags: numerical-methods, boundary-value-problem

I tried to solve this differential equation:

$$y''+\frac{1}{x}y'-\frac{9}{x^2}y=0\text{, where }x \in (1,2), y'(1)=\alpha, y(2)=\beta$$

I should use shooting method but I have a problem with boundaries because it is a mix of Neumann and Dirichlet boundary condition. Does anyone know how to transfer it only to Dirichlet boundary condition or how to solve it?

Thank you.

Comment: Try the guess $y = x^{r}$ and solve for $r$.

Comment: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/21498/numerical-method-for-a-bvp-with-mixed-boundary-conditions-matlab

Answer (score 1):

With $y = x^r$ we get that

$$r(r-1)x^{r-2} + rx^{r-2} - 9x^{r-2} = 0 \implies r^2-9 = 0$$

which means our two linearly independent solutions are

$$y = Ax^3 + Bx^{-3}$$

Plugging in the initial conditions gives us

$$\begin{cases}\alpha = 3A - 3B \\ \beta = 8A + \frac{1}{8}B\\ \end{cases} \implies \begin{cases}A = \frac{24\beta+\alpha}{195} \\ B = \frac{24\beta-64\alpha}{195} \\ \end{cases}$$